# Some more problem caused by EMI

Tags: led, stm32, emi-filtering

Before, I asked some ways to solve the EMI problem and I got some useful answer from here:
Really occasional malfunction of the Schmitt-trigger input - [Really occasional malfunction of the Schmitt-trigger input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/422591/208458)
However, another problem has risen.

My board has some adjacent LEDs near the 'trouble making area', and I revealed that sometimes they are powered off by my hand(Of course, I didn't touch the LEDs, I just brought my hand near the lights). For the 74HC14 problem, I added some capacitors to reduce the effect of the EMI and that was really successful. But, what can I do for these LEDs? LEDs are just connected by the MCU output pin, series connection with a resistor. For example, the part of the LED circuit will be MCU PIN->Resistor->LED->GND.

Ironically, this output pin indicates whether the network is on or off and even if the LED is off, the WiFi chip keeps connected to the server. So I think it is just output-related issue.

Would just adding some capacitors near the output pin going to GND be okay? If this is applicable, could I apply to similar situation?

[image]

- This is the part of the circuit. The board is perforated and there are so many adjacent connections(especially for 74HC14, near the LED).

[image]

[image]

These are somewhat more general circuit(showing nearly located circuits).

Comment: No, adding capacitors that way won't do anything. This is a bit of a shot in the dark but what if you put a high value resistor (maybe 10K) in parallel with the LED?

Comment: @Toor I have to preserve this 'fail' board because of some reasons(mainly, money). Is there no way to solve this issue with any methods?

Comment: You can't just hold a resistor to the LED pins on the board to test it out? If it fixes it you could just solder it straight on top of the LED. Or is this surface mount?

Comment: A capacitor might also work across the LED since it would short out EMI across the leads that might be turning it on.

Comment: @Toor I use SMT LEDs and SMT resistors. I do not use breadboard and they are soldered on the board(I know that SMT parts are generally for PCB boards but for size reduction I used some SMT parts). The problem is the LED shows if the network is connected. The LED output must be decided by the MCU output but if I bring my hand near the LED then LED sometimes tremble, flash or turned off.

Comment: What LED specifically, are you using? I've soldered similar SMD packages directly on top of each other before so if it matches an SMD component size you could do that. Put a cap or resistor right under the LED. But just test it out by holding a through hole resistor or capacitor to the LED and see if it helps. As I said before it's a shot in the dark so I don't even know if it will work.

Comment: @Toor I use a yellow SMT LED(I remember that Vf is almost 2V) and the size is 2012(in mm). The resistor(100ohms) has 2012 package too. The output pin will have 3.3V if the output pin is HIGH. As I described above, the circuit 'only for LED output' is that like. the LED-Pin wire length is almost 4 cm

Comment: I don't suppose you have 1k+ 2012 resistors as well do you? Or capacitors? Probably not since 2012s are really expensive. LED pin wire? I thought these are SMD. Post a photo of the circuit.

Comment: @Toor I added a picture and if the picture has lacking information, please ask for wider picture. The LED is at opposite site but the LED is REALLY SMD LED, and the clue is the brightness of the adjacent area of the board. Actually I thought using 1k+ resistor would not be adequate because I realized 3.3V output will not be adequate to produce enough current to LED.

Comment: The resistor I'm talking about adding is not the series current limiting resistor for the LED. It's a second resistor to go IN PARALLEL to the LED to try and drain of the excess charge away so that the LED won't light up just due to EMI.

Comment: How robust is the other end of the LEDs? That circuit seems to have NO PLANES, and EMI will cause voltage gradients everywhere.

Comment: Can I ask why you used a current sourcing set up to drive the LEDs rather then a sink?

Comment: @Jak Actually I hadn't considered about this, and in my university seniors did so... I'm just at 2nd grade, undergraduate and I sincerely faced the 'sinking' and 'sourcing' at this time first.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Yes, the board is just a prototype board and I didn't have mich money to use solely for PCBs... However after some incidents like this, I'm really considering using PCB. This board cannot have a ground plane because the board is like 'soldered breadboard'.